# How to use sed to remove lines with pattern in square brackets

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

How can I use sed and for loop to remove lines containing pattern in square brackets.

I have the following lines in a text file.

With 1st index goes from 0 to 6 and 2nd index goes from 0 to 3.

Lets say I only want to see [6][0~3]. So making this

```
portStateReport[2][0].xxxxx
portStateReport[2][1].xxxxx
portStateReport[2][2].xxxxx
portStateReport[6][0].xxxxx
```

to be something like

```
portStateReport[6][0].xxxxx
```

I am thinking of something like the following:

```
for (( i = 0; i < 4; i++)); do
   sed remove lines with patterns like "[2][i]" data.txt
done
```

I also tried the inverted grep with

```
grep -v "\["6]"\["0] data.txt
```

However, I don't know how to make it more dynamic that can also do [6][0~3].

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `grep` for this:

```
grep '\[6\]\[[0-3]\]' file

portStateReport[6][0].xxxx
```

Comment: hi I have a follow up question.

Comment: Why doesn't  '\[[5-10]\]\[[0-3]\]' work. It seems to grep everything if I set the range to [5-10]

Comment: In regex `5-10` doesn't mean `5` to `10`. For that you will need `([5-9]|10)`

Comment: That makes more sense :)   Can I do something like [0-3],[5-9] in the first square bracket, where it splits the ranges that I want to grep.

Comment: I also want to grep 10 and 11.  Can I do [0-35-9]|10|11? I tried this, and it does not work. Any tips regarding grep that find digits above 10.

Comment: Yes, you can do: `([0-35-9]|1[01])` Also [check this tutorial on regex numeric range checking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

Comment: Thank you so much.